# Bell numbers calculation in C

Tags: algorithm, c, mathematics

This is my implementation of the `bell()` function to calculate the n-th bell number in C.

Along with it I made the `factorial()` and `binomial()` functions.

I have serious doubts about their efficiency, in particular whether my implementation of the `factorial()` function should be correctly optimized for tail-recursion, and whether it is possible to rewrite the `bell()` to be more efficient.

Let me know any critics about my code, and if I can rely on this implementation or maybe use different approaches.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h> // For uint64_t
#include <inttypes.h> // For PRIu64

#define factorial(n) fact(n, 1)

static inline uint64_t fact(uint8_t n, uint64_t inc);
static inline uint64_t binomial(uint8_t n, uint8_t k);
static inline uint64_t bell(uint8_t n);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    printf("Bell: %" PRIu64 ".\n", bell(21));

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

// Tail recursion?
static inline uint64_t fact(uint8_t n, uint64_t inc) {
    return (n == 0) ? inc : fact(n - 1, inc * (uint64_t)n);
}

static inline uint64_t binomial(uint8_t n, uint8_t k) {
    return factorial(n) / (factorial(k) * factorial(n - k));
}

// can calculate up to bell(21)
static inline uint64_t bell(uint8_t n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    uint8_t i;
    uint64_t sum = 0;

    n--;

    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        sum += binomial(n, i) * bell(i);
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even without memoization, I cut the calculation time by about 40% when I switched from your version of `binomial` to the following:

```
static uint64_t permute(uint8_t n, uint8_t k) {
    uint64_t result = 1;

    for (; n > k; --n) {
        result *= n;
    }

    return result;
}

static inline uint64_t binomial(uint8_t n, uint8_t k) {
    if ( n - k > k ) {
        return permute(n, n - k) / permute(k, 1);
    } else {
        return permute(n, k) / permute(n - k, 1);
    }
}
```

Note that you could use the ternary operator rather than the `if` in `binomial`.

```
static inline uint64_t binomial(uint8_t n, uint8_t k) {
    return ( n - k > k ) 
        ? permute(n, n - k) / permute(k, 1)
        : permute(n, k) / permute(n - k, 1);
}
```

I find the `if` easier to follow in a complex statement like that.

The reason this works is that \$ \binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\$ can also be written as

$$ \frac{n * (n-1) * ... * (k+1)*k!}{k!(n-k)!} = \frac{n * (n-1) * ... * (k+1)}{(n-k)!} $$

and replacing `factorial(k)` with `permute(k, 1)` works because

$$ \frac{n!}{1!} = n! $$

It's unclear if memoization of the factorials would help more.  It may depend on how many values you need to calculate.

Comment: +1 for the alternative formula. I can see before trying it out it's more efficient.

@mdfst13 for the bell numbers I know I get an overflow when calculating `bell(22)`. I even thought I could just return the first 22 bell numbers using a simple switch/case instead. If you think about it, there are not much bell numbers that fit even into a `uint64_t`. That is if I can just write `uint64_t` number literals, right?

Answer (score 3):

- Computing binomials

  Using a formula \$ \binom{n}{i} = \frac{n!}{i!(n-i)!}\$ results in calculating very large numbers, and computing all the binomials your way you need to recompute factorials over and over again. An identity \$\binom{n}{i} =\frac{n-i + 1}{i} \binom{n}{i-1}\$ let you compute them on the fly:

  ```
  binomial = 1;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      sum += binomial * bell(i);
      binomial = binomial * (n - i + 1) / i;
  }
  ```
- Computing Bell numbers

  Your code recompute them recursively over and over again. You will gain quite a performance by memoizing them.

Comment: I thought about memoizing even with factorials and/or binomials.

Comment: Anyway there can be 21 numbers that can be saved in a 64-bit integer. It could even be a switch/case that returns one of those 21 

Comment: I tried comparing this method to my version, but I kept getting a runtime error, even after I changed it to start with `i = 1` to avoid the divide by zero error.

Comment: @Zorgatone  `bell(22)` is 0x1ADCB3D5, which is only 61 bits.  You just can't calculate it in 64-bit integers with your method.  You might manage with a different, more complicated method.  Or of course you could use a larger integer size to hold the intermediate results.

Comment: @vnp yeah @mdfst13 is right, without even trying it out, I can see there is a division by `i` in the first loop iteration with `i = 0`.

Comment: @mdfst13  You are right; there is off-by-one error. Consider it a pseudocode. Point is still valid.